# How do I tell py.test to not prepend to sys.path?

Tags: pytest

When running py.test, it seems to automatically prepend your project's root directory (one above the last `__init__.py`) to sys.path

This is causing some issues for me, I looked through the docs but could not find any option for this.

Does anyone know a way?

Thanks

Comment: Then it's not sys.path, or `PATH`. It's more likely `PYTHONPATH` issue. Could you provide sample error from py.test? Is package you trying to test is installed package?

Comment: sys.path is initialized from PYTHONPATH.  there is no error, it's just trying to import from the wrong location

Comment: I don't think py.test adds the project root to `sys.path`, but as a side-effect of how it imports the `conftest.py` files any directory with `conftest.py` in will end up on `sys.path`.  So do you have a `conftest.py` which triggers this behaviour?